# Android: inherit from values/styles.xml

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a question about android styles.xml

Now my values/styles.xml is

```
<style name="LV_Testo_Standard">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">6</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#39AEFF</item>
</style>
```

Reading some tutorial in internet, if I want to add some new features like "font-family" (not supported in version below v.16), etc, I must create a new folder "values-v16" and create new "styles.xml" file for Android with this version and above.

My doubt is about the items in styles in this new version of styles.xml.

Inside values-v16/styles.xml must I add only this:

```
 <style name="LV_Testo_Standard" parent="LV_Testo_Standard">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

or all values/styles.xml plus this new two items?

```
<style name="LV_Testo_Standard">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">6</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#39AEFF</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item> <!-- NEW -->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> <!-- NEW -->
</style>
```

Sorry for my english.. Hope you'll understand

Tnx

Comment: All values. you can always try that yourself and see which one works for you. Good luck ^^ ;)

Comment: With `values-v16` dir you are targeting API 16-17-18 ...
If I understand correct you want prior to 16.

Comment: Thank you all for for your answers
I asked because i thought there was some kind of import mechanism...
So, it's a boring process if i were to use a complete "styles.xml" in all "values" folders..
@mt0s: I'm sorry, my english is less than that a monkey that does not speak english :p
What I want is create a styles.xml generic and one specific for android >= 4.1

Comment: @crc_error Did you get a solution for this like making a generic in values folder and inheriting it in say, values-v21?. Is there some solution to this ?

Answer (score -2):

@crc_error

As you have studied it from the Internet, Different folders fo the values are made to give the unique style when your application is running on the specific version of Android.

For eg. values - is supported in lower version and overall.. so your textcolor changes for all
Now values-14 - so ICS you want the font family of the text should be different (so this changes you have to add in style.xml of values-14)
Now values-16 - Latest android supported, you want the all text should be bold and italic than you should add it here in style.xml

```
values is targeting the API inferior to 11
values-v11 is targeting the API between 11 and 13
values-v14 is targeting the API superior to 13
```

In Brief in u want same functionlaity in all than only values addition is enough when u want changes as the android version increases than u need to add it in these files.